# Entity Framework foreach on table over 800,000 records

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

What is the correct method for iterating through a table with a large number of records?  I need to evaluate ever record in the table.  I am using Entity Framework to connect and get the information from the MS SQL database.  I was using a simple `foreach` loop;

```
foreach (var x in MyEntity.MyTable)
{
   //logic process
}
```

This works perfectly for tables less than 500,000 records (don't have exact numbers).  The problem is when it hits larger tables say 800,000 plus records the application becomes unstable and will crash.  I should note that app is using lots of RAM (around 4-6GB)

Comment: Implement paging. Very unlikely you need all records in memory at once. Also, applications don't simply "become unstable and crash", they give an exception. Did you try researching that exception?

Comment: Do your process chunk wise. Or try to make this operation SQL only.

Comment: Process 500k records at a time?

Comment: If you have to evaluate every record, try to do it not in-memory, but in database. What are you trying to evaluate?

Comment: @CodeCaster it actually is very likely I need all records.  It is an export of all data to another database.  So I need every row

Comment: Yeah, so, paging. You don't need them all in memory at once. You can load them in batches of 1000 for example. The answer you accepted will break again once the amount of data reaches new thresholds.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks, I will do that.  If you would have put that as the answer would have gone with that.  Saw the answer below and it worked.   Then saw your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx)

```
foreach (var x in MyEntity.MyTable.AsNoTracking())
```

This will ensure that as each item in the table is iterated over it is not tracked by EF and will not stick around in the `DbContext` so the instance can be GC'ed by the CLR when necessary.

Note that this means you can't make any changes on the item and expect to persist those back to the DbContext, you would have to attach the instance to do that.

---

*This does assume that there are not other issues in the code you have not shown that consume large amounts of memory.*

Comment: This will still fire off a query that requests 800K records from the database, which is most likely unnecessary.